# Caching ionic 2 first load not resolving data

Tags: caching, ionic-framework, promise, ionic2

I use a plugin [ionic-cache](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache) to cache all my requests in a ionic 2 app. Problem is the first time when there is no cache available the data is not resolving. The second load the data is available and the app works fine.

My api service:

```
getPosts(category, count) {

        return new Promise(resolve => {    
            let key = `${URL.getPosts}?post_type=post&count=${count}&cat=${category}`;
            this.cache.getItem(key)
            .catch(() => {
                // fallback if item is expired or doesn't exist
                return this.http.get(key)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        // save response to cache
                        this.cache.saveItem(key, data);
                        this.data = data;
                        resolve(this.data);
                });
            }).then((data) => {
                 this.data = data;
                 resolve(this.data);
            });
        });
    }
```

my pageComponent call to the apiservice:

```
loadPosts(){

    let count = 15;
    let category = 24;

    this.GetApi.getPosts(category,count).then(
        data => {
            this.create( data );
        }
    );
}

create(data){
    this.items = data.posts;
}
```

Comment: Try getting rid of your return on this.http.get(key).  Looks funky

Comment: I tried but no luck

Comment: Next thing I would try is to supply a error function in your http call to make sure there is no error.  Maybe also console.log on the successful http call?

Comment: The call is successful but the angular template can't read the post data the first time it not resolving. After refresh the page it is resolving because the catch has added the response to the cache